# How big of a buffer should I create for the longest possible user or group name on Linux?

Tags: linux, max, string-length

What is the maximum number of characters that a user name or group name may be on Linux?

I need to allocate a buffer and would like to know how much space I need to allocate to guarantee it is large enough for whatever group or user name my application might encounter.

Comment: This might very well be programming related, e.g. if the OP wants to know how much buffer space he must, at most, allocate for storing user/group names. E.g. consider getpwnam_r() and sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX).

Comment: Or to answer the question partially, see the LOGIN_NAME_MAX macro which must be at least 9 but might be bigger; On Linux it seems to be 256. For group name limits, I don't know.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that this is indeed a programming related question since the string-length tag was too subtle.

Comment: Why was this closed AFTER the programming nature was clarified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Putting my comment into an answer now that the question has been reopened)

POSIX specifies that LOGIN_NAME_MAX must be >= _POSIX_LOGIN_NAME_MAX. _POSIX_LOGIN_NAME_MAX, in turn, is defined to 9. On Linux it seems LOGIN_NAME_MAX is 256.

For groups, I don't think there is anything similar. Some kind of upper bound can be guesstimated via the getgrnam_r() and getgrgid_r() functions, which take a user supplied buffer for the char* entries in struct group. The maximum needed size for this buffer can be retrieved via sysconf(_SC_GETGR_R_SIZE_MAX) or the macro NSS_BUFLEN_GROUP. On Linux, NSS_BUFLEN_GROUP seems to be 1024.